# SQL Server : Inner Join using bottom most row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table referred to as 'attLog' which has the empID along with the time that they clocked out of work and also serialNo that counts up by one. I innerjoin this with a table know as 'employees' but when doing so it gives me the result closest to the top, but I need the most recent or most bottom result.

dbo.attLog

```
empID | time   | DATE      | serialNo
------+--------+-----------+----------
1001  | 5.01PM | 2020-10-1 | 1
1002  | 5.04PM | 2020-10-1 | 2
1002  | 5.02PM | 2020-10-2 | 3
1001  | 5.04PM | 2020-10-2 | 4
1002  | 5.15PM | 2020-10-2 | 5
```

This is the result that I get when I run the query..

dbo.employees

```
empID | latestTime
------+-----------
1001  | 5.04PM
1002  | 5.02PM
```

This is the result that I wish to happen..

dbo.employees

```
empID | latestTime
------+-----------
1001  | 5.04PM
1002  | 5.15PM
```

Here is my query that I am using..

```
UPDATE employees
SET employees.latestTime = attLog.time
FROM employees employees
INNER JOIN attLog attLog ON employees.empID = attLog.empID
WHERE attLog.authDate = '2020-10-2'
```

Thank you very much. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate the table first and then join:

```
UPDATE e
    SET e.latestTime = al.max_time
    FROM employees e JOIN
         (SELECT al.empId, MAX(al.time) as max_time
          FROM attLog al
          WHERE al.authDate = '2020-10-02'
          GROUP BY al.empId
         ) al
         ON e.empID = al.empID;
```